# Breeze validation tests in Jasmine

Tags: validation, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, breeze

Has anyone successfully used Jasmine to unit test validation in a Breeze based application?  For the record, I'm also using Angular.

Any pattern insights or a fiddle would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do a lot of it.

In fact, I'm presenting about it, "[Async JavaScript Testing](http://devintersection.com/sessions.aspx)", at the [DevIntersections Conference](http://devintersection.com/dev.aspx) in Orlando in April. I'll have posted the slides by the end of the month along with an updated "[Breeze Zza Sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza)" showing the tests.

Help is on the way.

Comment: Thanks Ward.  Great answer, as usual.  I'll look for your posts.  How about a Pluralsight course on advanced Breeze, including tests?

Comment: Might happen. Tell them you want it :-)